# domain class property representation on the page

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class with property which stores HTML text. I want to show this HTML directly on the page, so I want to use it in such way:

```
<head>
..
</head>
<body>
   ${instance.HTML}
</body>
```

suppose instance.HTML equals to `<a>some text</a>`
what I get is:

```
<head>
..
</head>
<body>
   "<a>some text</a>"
</body>
```

but what I actually want to achieve is just

```
<head>
..
</head>
<body>
   <a>some text</a>
</body>
```

How to delete those quotes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of security feature of grails: [Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Prevention](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#xssPrevention)

Try `raw` like

```
${raw(instance.HTML)}
```

OR

add page directive like:

```
<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>
```